# Problems writing udev rule for gaming mouse

Tags: mouse, udev, joystick

TL;DR is that I have a fancy gaming mouse that I want to disable some of the features of but not all, and it's tricky to pinpoint them. I'm using
`SUBSYSTEM=="input",ATTRS{serial}=="SZH410946",ACTION=="add",ENV{DEVLINK}=="/dev/input/by-id/usb-Swiftpoint_Limited_Swiftpoint_Z_SZH410946-if02-joystick",MODE="0000"` but it's not getting the 000 part.

The long version. I have a Swiftpoint Z mouse that I'm pretty fond of. It's a gaming mouse with all kinds of buttons, gyros, etc. in it. Sadly, like too many things, it seems like Linux support is off the table for the devs of it, but I can configure it in Win-blows and save the config to onboard storage on the mouse. This works great, for most things.
The actual problem I'm trying to solve is that in order to work, the mouse emulates a keyboard, mouse, and joystick, over a number of devices. The joystick in particular is causing me the grief. Quite a few of my games pick it up and treat it at controller 1, and several of the axis on this fake device are pegged, causing all kinds of mayham. I have learned to look at the device that it gets set to and just `sudo rm /dev/input/js**x**`, etc. but that's pretty tedious after each reboot, and I like learning new things, so I set about learning udev.

So the first issue, is that not much identifies the joystick and event devices from say, the mouse or keyboard part. I've been trying to isolate it with `ENV{DEVLINK}=="path/to/device"` and I think it's matching, at least when I run `sudo udevadm test blah blah` it seems to get it. But my `MODE="0000"` doesn't seem to want to work right. I also tried `` RUN+="/usr/bin/rm `readlink -f /path/to/dev`" `` which also seemed to do nothing.

Another thing I noticed, is before I had the `ENV{DEVLINK}=="path/to/device"` part, is that it would blow away the joystick (along with the rest of my mouse) but only with the `udevadm test` command. Simply plugging the device in did nothing.

I have been thinking of just running a script with it that can do the `rm` for me, but... eh... it feels less clean than just learning what I'm doing wrong and fixing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: copy `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules` to your `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules`, put your rule in the beginning, and append `GOTO="persistent_input_end"` this should skip the creation of the symlink.

Comment: think you are looking for [how to disable USB devices...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. In fact, I can't tell that it's doing anything at all...

Comment: maybe "[Disable mouse and touchpad with shell script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317306/986805)" will work better?