# Disable mouse and touchpad with shell script

Tags: usb, scripts, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

Due to unfortunate event, my mouse seems to have gone into a permanently clicked state making my laptop nearly unusable. Otherwise, the hardware (audio, HDMI, USB and even keyboard, etc.) and the OS works perfectly. I am now using an external keyboard and mouse to work with my laptop. But, the issue of permanently clicked mouse still persists.

Therefore, can you give me a shell script that *COMPLETELY* disables mouse and touchpad? The OS should feel that, mouse and touchpad does not even exist on the laptop; but, the mouse is connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to *permanently* disable an input device, there are a couple of ways to do this via the commandline.

#### Option 1: Use `xinput`

From within Terminal, list all of the input devices currently registered with your computer:

```
xinput list
```

This should give you something that looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3289-002                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Identify which device(s) you do not want to have active and type this:

```
xinput set-prop {id} "Device Enabled" 0
```

***Note:** Be sure to replace `{id}` with the proper ID of your device.*

If you accidentally entered the wrong value for `{id}`, or you would like to re-enable the device at a later date, simply run the command again replacing `0` with `1`.

#### Option 2: Use Gnome Settings

From within Terminal, set Gnome's `touchpad-enabled` value to `false`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

This will ensure the touchpad is disabled until the next time you reboot. If you would like to use this method to always disable the touchpad, add this to your Startup Applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

#### Option 3: Remove the Synaptics driver

This one is a bit more brute force, and it's also the only option that requires the use of `sudo`. Open Terminal and remove Synaptics:

```
sudo apt remove --purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Note that this will also remove the `xserver-xorg-input-all` package, as you can't have "all" if you're missing stuff, but it will not affect your keyboard or external peripherals.

Hopefully one of these will give you what you need